# Use a JInternalFrame to create a chat window in a client/server app

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

How to use a `JInternalFrame` within a `JFrame`?

I want to create a client/server app.
I know that `JInternalFrame` should be used with `JDeskTopPane` but I want a chat window which can be moved within the app (just like chatting in Facebook).

1. How to use `JInternalFrame` for this?
2. Do you suggest any other Swing component for this?

Comment: *"`JDeskTopPane` but I want a chat window which can be moved within the app (just like chatting in Facebook)."*  Put a `JInternalFrame` into a `JDesktopPane` and the user can move it at will.  E.G. as seen in [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859258/java-swing-internal-frame-as-dialog/13859951#13859951) after the internal dialog is closed.

Comment: As said use a JDesktopPane with your JInternalFrame. here is a nice example too http://stackoverflow.com/a/13815721/1133011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here is the short working example of what you are looking for.
Code:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jInternalFrame1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
    jInternalFrame1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(7, 7, 7, 7, new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
    jInternalFrame1.setTitle("This is JInternal Frame");
    jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 386, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 304, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jInternalFrame1)
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
    );

    pack();
}
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
 }


private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;

}
```

See [*How to Use Internal Frames*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) for more.

**EDIT:**

P.S - I have taken help of `JPanel`. If you wish to hide the component anytime,
use `setVisible(false)` insted of `foo.setVisible(false)`.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Suggestions: 1) Please don't cite old (1.4.2?!) documentation unless required. 2) From the tutorial cited, "Usually, you add internal frames to a desktop pane." 3) Using a GUI designer needlessly complicates your example code. 4) See also how to take a [screenshot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post).